# Bootstrap fixed height size column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to turn a bootstrap 3 `col-lg-x` into a "fixed height size" column with vertical scrolling bar? I did many research and tried several CSS codes but no way.

**Update:** I have this code, but it's scrolling horizontally:

```
.scrollablepage > :last-child
{
height:552px;
overflow-y:scroll;  
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 scrollablepage">
        <div class="well well-sm"> 
            <p> 
                hellohellohel lohellohellohellohell ohellohellohellohellohelloh ellohellohellohe
                llohellohel lohelellohellohellohell ohellohellohel lohellohellohellohell
                ohellohellohellohelloh  ellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohel
            </p>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Why it's scrolling horizontally and not vertically?

Comment: Have you tried to apply `height` and `overflow-y` properties to the column?

Comment: @HashemQolami Tried with `height:500px`, and `overflow-y:scroll` (and auto). This is not working:

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsbin.com/tonuxoqi/1/edit

Comment: @HashemQolami I didn't know about `:lastchild` selector, thank you very much!

Comment: @HashemQolami Can you check my update please.

Comment: Please note that using `:last-child` pseudo class wasn't the case. I just used that to select the proper element. Here is a [different demo](http://jsbin.com/tonuxoqi/3/edit). In your particular instance, you could use those CSS declarations on `.scrollablepage` selector instead. **[Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/tonuxoqi/4/edit)**.

Comment: @HashemQolami The problem was because I had a very long phrase without spacing. It's solved, and I don't know if I should delete the question. Thank you very much for the information!